# Configuring electron-webpack renderer to work with nodeIntegration: false

Tags: webpack, electron

I'm attempting to configure electron-webpack's renderer build settings so that they work in a browser window set up with `nodeIntegration` set to false.  This means that node APIs aren't available, which is causing the following problems:

- webpack seems to be assuming that there is an implementation of `require` already available so isn't including its own in the produced bundle, but instead is simply adding the bundled definitions into `module.exports` (causing an error that `module` isn't defined when the bundle is loaded)
- `html-webpack-plugin` is being used to produce the index.html file, and is adding `<script>require("source-map-support/source-map-support.js").install()</script>` to the output, before the bundle is loaded.  This line needs to be moved to after the bundle load line, but don't see any way of doing this.

I've tried setting up the following in my `package.json`:

```json
"electronWebpack": {
  "renderer": {
    "webpackConfig": "renderer.additions.webpack.js"
  }
}
```

with the `renderer.additions.webpack.js` file containing:

```js
module.exports = {
    target: 'web',          // node integration is turned off, so use standard web settings.
    externals: ['electron'] // do not rely on ability to load code externally: only specifically known-preloaded modules are to be excluded from the package
}
```

but this doesn't seem to have changed anything at all.  Any suggestions how to make this work?

Comment: Any solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: found this gist https://gist.github.com/earksiinni/053470a04defc6d7dfaacd5e5a073b15 but it doesn't help when compiling for production

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, [electron-webpack](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack) is a template used to connect Electron apps with Webpack. It seems this project is in maintenance mode and isn't active right now.

I've created a template of Electron and Webpack (albeit a few versions out of date currently with the newest version of the Electron framework) that still works and can be used as a starting point. There are a lot of files involved in setting up this connection, more-so than would be helpful in this stackoverflow answer, so instead I'll point you to the repo: [`secure-electron-template`](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template).