# Setting nodeIntegration: false when using create-react-app-typescript and electron

Tags: webpack, electron, create-react-app

I'm experiencing an issue when using electron in combination with [create-react-app-typescript](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript). For security reasons it's advised to set `nodeIntegration: false` when creating a new electron `browserWindow`(to avoid XSS). You should then expose the node API's you need via the `preload` script by attaching those to `global` or `window`. I did this with the `electron` package but doesn't get attached to the `window` and I'm getting an error; `ReferenceError: require is not defined` on  `module.exports = require("electron");` in the bundle.

Anyone has an idea what I'm overlooking? I'm using the default webpack of the create-react-app-typescript library (I ejected the app). Also, the app should work on both electron and in the browser. I'd love some help or anyone that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I believe you have the same problem as this user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705639/configuring-electron-webpack-renderer-to-work-with-nodeintegration-false

There's no complete answer, but the [linked gist](https://gist.github.com/earksiinni/053470a04defc6d7dfaacd5e5a073b15) may be a useful starting point.